# Save position of inputs in HTML table to SQL Server

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, html

I'm trying to make a page that allows users to drag and drop HTML form inputs into a table to format the page. The fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jdavid05/jtoka8f5/3/).

Does anyone know if it is possible to save the position of the inputs in the HTML table to an SQL Server table using PHP?

The tables can be dynamically updated by clicking buttons to add rows and columns:

```
<table name="row[]" style="width: 97%; display: block; clear: both; float: left;">
            <tr>
                <td><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="add_champ" style="float: left">+col</button></td>
                <td style="width: 700px; border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="remove_row" style="float: left">- col</button></td>
                <td style="width: 700px; border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="remove_row" style="float: left">- col</button></td>
                <td style="width: 700px; border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="remove_row" style="float: left">- col</button></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
```

Basically, I want to be able to reproduce the table (without borders or buttons) in another page. To do this, I was hoping I could cycle through every table and save the data enclosed in the td tags.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Cheers,

Comment: It's not a direct/complete answer to your question, but have you considered using jQuery UI's [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/), [Droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/), and [Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)?  Might make your life a bit easier.

Comment: I had looked at those. They are really interesting, and I've used them for other things (usually just updating the order of list items in lookup tables). But, I couldn't figure out a good way to create a page layout with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if it is possible to save the position of the inputs in the HTML table to an SQL Server table using PHP?

Yes, that should be possible!

> I want to be able to reproduce the table in another page. To do this, I was hoping I could cycle through every table and save the data enclosed in the td tags.

Sounds feasible!

All you need is a clever way to structure your data, so that retrieving and recreating the table isn't overly complicated and prone to bugs and errors.

You probably need to save some meta data about the table, and perhaps about each cell, as well.

For example: how many rows and colums does the table have, and how do you map the content to each table?

I'd probably create different SQL tables and link the ids:

So one table `td_contents` with the fields `content`, `table_id`, `row_id` and `column_id`.

The ids then all match a set in their corresponding tables, so that you can store plenty of metadata about everything, while still keeping it flexible and editable.

Your best approach is probably to really think about which metadata you want and need to make this happen.